# Wayland - Find out whether compositor decorates windows

Tags: window-decoration, wayland

I have seen this question: [Can't a Wayland compositor do the window decorations like on X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059798/cant-a-wayland-compositor-do-the-window-decorations-like-on-x), but I'm wondering this:

Say I write an application using pure wayland, how do I know if the server will decorate the window? I want to support compositors who *don't* decorate, and compositors who *do* decorate (on the ones who don't, the application will decorate it manually).

Is this possible? If not, is this theoretically possible with the current wayland API (i.e. some kind of weird message passing that would require standardization)? And if not, why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no standardised way to identify whether the compositor decorates the windows. That being said I am not aware of any Wayland compositors that do server side decoration and all major toolkits (GTK, QT, Elementary) use client side decoration when running against Wayland.

Comment: maybe Wayland devs can add a way to request this?

Comment: Thinks seem to have changed. Pardon me, if my understanding is wrong. In order to have window decorations, a compositor needs to implement the *global* `zxdg_decoration_manager_v1` interface. Windows that wish to have decorations then need to retrieve a toplevel surface by passing a `xdg_toplevel` object to `get_toplevel_decoration`.

However, some Compositors like GNOME's Mutter do not implement this surface, sadly, requiring to create your own decorations.